# How to solr index merging is done

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, lucene, solr

How to Solr index merging is done and configure solrconfig.xml.

1. when i go to create index create indexes but do not get they are merged

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about merging different Solr indexes, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MergingSolrIndexes